# Enable listen hook in production in Nuxt

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

Anybody know how to enable the listen `hook` in `Nuxt` in `production` ?
It works with `npm run dev` (dev) but not with `npm run build & npm run preview` (production)

I want to have access to the node server to link it with a `WebSocketServer`, this is my `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    

        hooks: {
            listen(server) {
                console.log(server)

                const yogaApp = createYoga({
                    graphqlEndpoint: '/api/graphql',
                    schema: createSchema({
                        typeDefs: /* GraphQL */ `
                            type Query {
                                hello: String
                            }

                            type Subscription {
                                countdown(from: Int!): Int!
                            }
                        `,
                        resolvers: {
                            Query: {
                                hello: () => 'world'
                            },
                            Subscription: {
                                countdown: {
                                    // This will return the value on every 1 sec until it reaches 0
                                    subscribe: async function* (_, { from }) {
                                        for (let i = from; i >= 0; i--) {
                                            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
                                            yield { countdown: i }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }),
                    graphiql:{
                        subscriptionsProtocol: "WS"
                    }
                })

                console.log(yogaApp.graphqlEndpoint)

                // Get NodeJS Server from Yoga
                // Create WebSocket server instance from our Node server
                const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
                    server,
                    path: yogaApp.graphqlEndpoint
                })

                // Integrate Yoga's Envelop instance and NodeJS server with graphql-ws
                useServer(
                    {
                        execute: (args: any) => args.rootValue.execute(args),
                        subscribe: (args: any) => args.rootValue.subscribe(args),
                        onSubscribe: async (ctx, msg) => {
                            const { schema, execute, subscribe, contextFactory, parse, validate } =
                                yogaApp.getEnveloped({
                                    ...ctx,
                                    req: ctx.extra.request,
                                    socket: ctx.extra.socket,
                                    params: msg.payload
                                })

                            const args = {
                                schema,
                                operationName: msg.payload.operationName,
                                document: parse(msg.payload.query),
                                variableValues: msg.payload.variables,
                                contextValue: await contextFactory(),
                                rootValue: {
                                    execute,
                                    subscribe
                                }
                            }

                            const errors = validate(args.schema, args.document)
                            if (errors.length) return errors
                            return args
                        }
                    },
                    wsServer
                )
            }
        },

})
```

Comment: Do you have `start` script on top of `preview`? Because that is supposed to work well: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/internals-nuxt#hooks

Comment: nope it's the same with start before preview

Comment: when we use the build and not the dev server it does not trigger the listen hook

Comment: No, what are your `start` and `preview` scripts doing in `package.json`?

Comment: nuxt start and nuxt preview